# Wallaby and Haml - how to make it work?

Tags: haml, frontend, wallaby.js

Lately I have integrated **Wallaby** to my project, the DOM in this project is programmed with **HAML** instead of HTML, as long as I change Typescript / Javascript files Wallaby works great and tells me immediately which tests  failed / passed, but when I change HAML files Wallaby just losing it and unless I restart Wallaby it will ignore the HAML changes and sometimes even stop running tests.

Is there any way to make them work together properly? So far with Karma as a TDD framework I had no such issues.

Just a note - I am a Front End developer and an obsessive TDD programmer, so Wallaby suits my needs perfectly.

Comment: If you're using webpack, make sure to update wallaby-webpack module to the latest. Few days ago wallaby added support for catching changes in non-instrumented files: https://twitter.com/wallabyjs/status/818306431786958850